# I wish to expand my LVM2 partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted, lvm

When I run gparted I show the following partitions...

```
/dev/sda1       ext2       243mb      boot
/dev/sda2       extended   39.76 gb
/dev/sda5       lvm2       39.76 gb   lvm
unallocated                70 gb
```

and when I choose to expand the `lvm2` it gives the "warning:logical volume management is not yet supported"
Is it safe to use the `lvextend` and `resize2fs` commands to expand the `lvm2` so it uses the unallocated space?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must extend containers from the outermost to the innermost. In your example, you have

1. An extended partition, `sda2`, which contains ...
2. A logical partition, `sda5`, which contains ...
3. An LVM physical volume, which contains ...
4. An LVM volume group, which probably contains ...
5. One or more LVM logical volume, some of which may contain ...
6. File systems.

It is always recommended to back up your system before fiddling with partitions and file systems; generally the process of extending partitions, LVM physical volumes and filesystems is not dangerous provided that the operator pays attention and makes no mistakes. Any human may make mistakes, and that's why you should back up the system before proceeding.

Best is to boot from the installation media: things go smoothly when file systems are not mounted. I have never tried to extend or move partitions while they were in use by the system; I always boot from the live installation media (or from a dedicated live DVD) when I need to change the partitioning scheme.

1. You must first extend the extended partition `sda2`; you can use `gparted` or `parted` to extend the partition. If you use `gparted` and it displays a small key near the partition name, it means that the partition is active and therefore locked; right click and select deactivate to unlock it.
2. After extending `sda2` you may extend `sda5`, which now has room to grow. Use `gparted` or `parted` to extend it.
3. After extending `sda5` the partition you can extend `sda5` the LVM physical disk. Use `pvresize` in a terminal:

   sudo pvresize /dev/sda5
4. Resizing the physical volume will automatically resize the volume group, because a volume group is just a list of one or more physical volumes. Now that you have the volume group resized, you may resize any logical volume inside it using `lvresize`.

   - To find out how much space you now have available in the volume group use the command `vgs`:

     sudo vgs
   - This will display a nicely formatted table; look under `VFree` to find out how much space is available. You did not say what the names of the volume group and logical volumes are, so for example I will use the volume group name `sda5_vg` and the logical volume name `sys_lv`, and extend it by 10 GiB:

     sudo lvresize -L +10g -r /dev/mapper/sda5_vg-sys_lv
   - You will of course need to adjust the amount of disk space and the names of the volume group and of the logical volume(s).
   - The option `-r` tells `lvresize` to extend the file system inside the logical volume to match the new size.

That's it. You may now reboot the system, and use `df` to check that your file systems have been extended.

**Note:** This procedure has been tested on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: So I don't need to worry about the "warning: logical volume management is not yet supported" error in gparted??

Comment: I don't see that warning. What version of operating system/gparted are you using? My gparted does not even attempt to do anything with the LVM physical volume.