# My 1TB NVMe drive is only being shown as 98gb

Tags: server, minecraft, nvme

I recently made an Ubuntu server to host my Minecraft server.
I am running Ubuntu 21.10

When I logged in I got this message:

```
  Usage of /:                    92.6% of 97.87GB
```

The NVMe I have is 1tb, I didn't realise when I was installing that the full 1tb wasn't recognised.

After running the command `sudo vgdisplay` I get this in my output:

```
  Alloc PE / Size       25600 / 100.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       212213 / <828.96 GiB
```

So it does detect the 828+gb but hasn't allocated it.
How do I allocate this extra space?

UPDATE:
After running `sudo lsblk` I get

```
nvme0n1                   259:0    0 931.5G  0 disk
├─nvme0n1p1               259:1    0     1G  0 part /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               259:2    0   1.5G  0 part /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               259:3    0   929G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0   100G  0 lvm  /
```

Comment: `sudo lsblk` will list the partitions, `mount` will show filesystems in use. `df` will show information,  too

Comment: Since LVM or volumes: http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume I think most suggest smaller root and create larger data volume(s).

Comment: @waltinator I updated my question to show the output of lsblk

Comment: lsblk does not need `sudo` - e.g. `$ lsblk | grep -v loop` will show all disks and partitions except those on loop devices (many, created by `snap`)