# Disk space is not partitioned properly

Tags: partitioning, 20.04

I recently set up a new Ubuntu Server running 20.04 after install I realized that something is terribly wrong with how this is set up. The server is 1TB in size, but for whatever reason it thinks that it's only 100GB. Can someone please help me fix this? Thanks in advance.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If this is a new installation, why not start over? If you want to use the whole disk, make sure that you format it ahead of time.

Comment: I know two graphical apps that can help you to work on this visually. One is Ubuntu's standard "Disks" app, and the other is "Gparted", which you can install. Both will offer a visual overview of your disk utilization and will offer functions to resize partitions. But before you actually get into resizing, make a safety copy of every file that's important for you. Actions that modify partitions are not exactly very complicated, but there is no guarantee for 100% success. That's why the safety backup beforehand is adviseable.

Comment: The *partitioning* (sda1/sda2/sda3) looks correct. Use LVM tools to extend your root (`/`) LV to fill the entire sda3 partition.

Comment: You are using LVM or logical volumes. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuDesktopLVM  & http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition

Comment: This is a particularly clear tutorial about how to do this. https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Comment: Thanks everyone. I actually found the answers here. https://www.linuxtechi.com/extend-lvm-partitions/

Answer (score 0):

gparted. It has a gui that's really userfriendly. I cloned a 160GB HDD to a 1TB HDD and I was able to use gparted to resize the ext4 partition to the full size of the disk. If you have to move your swap partition you'll need to go into your fstab file and change the uuid.