# Extending partition

Tags: partitioning

I would like to ask how to extend disk partition. My server has 500G disk but it only uses 100G for the file system. Would it be possible to resize it the full size of the disk? Thanks for your help.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iPSDE.png)

Comment: It looks like partition is full size, so you just need to extend LVM. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444855&p=13963156#post13963156

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)

Comment: This is a good guide to understanding and extending LVM