# Parted shows 2TB partition, but df says it's 98GB

Tags: disk-usage, lvm, df, parted

I ran out of space on my root partition, df outputs:

```
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              3.1G  2.0M  3.1G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   98G     0 100% /
tmpfs                               16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  379M  1.5G  21% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              3.1G  4.0K  3.1G   1% /run/user/1000
```

The lvm volume group has ~2TB:

```
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               ubuntu-vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        2
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                1
  Open LV               1
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                2
  Act PV                2
  VG Size               1.86 TiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              487599
  Alloc PE / Size       487599 / 1.86 TiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0
  VG UUID               5faYrE-8xXv-a4A7-yD6L-acvL-w0rr-Qx9oNN
```

And the logical volume also shows ~2TB:

```
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv
  LV Name                ubuntu-lv
  VG Name                ubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                y2SzMl-qmb6-cr3r-wphB-6F28-3xfs-nJXN7Y
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time ubuntu-server, 2022-07-21 19:40:30 +0000
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                1.86 TiB
  Current LE             487599
  Segments               2
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           253:0
```

So I assumed I just needed to extend the partition, but when I go to expand the partition with parted it already shows it as 2TB.

```
parted /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
GNU Parted 3.4
Using /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
Welcome to GNU Parted! Type 'help' to view a list of commands.
(parted) print
Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 2045GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0.00B  2045GB  2045GB  ext4

(parted)
```

Does anyone know what I'm missing here? Why is `/` only 98G when both lvm and parted imply that it's much larger than that?

Comment: Most that use LVM, want a smaller / (root) and add volumes for data or /home. So default does not use entire volume. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444855&p=13963156#post13963156

Answer (score 0):

It looks like:

```
sudo resize2fs /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv
```

Fixed my issue.