# How to create a Useable Partition from Ubuntu OS Installation Partition

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I have a problem with using the free space on my current disk, somehow the only space visible on the 512GB disk is 105GB.

Partition Break-down

- Model: ATA SSD 512GB (scsi)
- Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
- Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
- Partition Table: gpt
- Disk Flags:
- Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
- 1      1049kB  1128MB  1127MB  fat32              boot, esp
- 2      1128MB  3276MB  2147MB  ext4
- 3      3276MB  512GB   509GB
- Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
- Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 107GB
- Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
- Partition Table: loop
- Disk Flags:
- Number  Start  End    Size   File system  Flags
- 1      0.00B  107GB  107GB  ext4

Considering that I have 512GB SSD and 105GB is an LVM partition used for the OS installation, [image]

But the main disk is in SDA3 512GB along with the Freespace, but the free space is not visible on the useable partition in the previous image above. (see attached here [image]

Question is:
My challenge is, instead of seeing the entire 473GB on my PC which is where the OS is installed, I can only see 105GB, any ideas.?

Thanks in anticipation.

Sam

Comment: I do not use LVM, but I understand it is difficult to shrink and very easy to expand. Default install does not use all the available space so you can either add volumes for /home or data or expand your / volume. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this tutorial. https://www.tecmint.com/extend-and-reduce-lvms-in-linux/

Follow the process from the heading “Extending Volume Group”. You can probably skip to the vgdisplay command. You should have a large amount of free PE. Follow the tutorial from there.

Good luck