# How can I increase the size of lvm partition?

Tags: 18.04, partitioning, lvm

I have a ubuntu 18.04 system. I have a total of 3 partitions and in my third partition, I have an LVM partition. I need to increase the size of that partition. Here is the output of `lsblk` I need to increase the size of `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` partition inside `/dev/sda3`

```
NAME                      MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                         8:0    0  140G  0 disk
├─sda1                      8:1    0    1M  0 part
├─sda2                      8:2    0    1G  0 part /boot
└─sda3                      8:3    0   49G  0 part
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv 253:0    0 24.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0                        11:0    1  969M  0 rom
```

Here is the output of `df-h`

```
udev                               3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs                              789M  1.3M  787M   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   24G   22G  1.4G  95% /
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                              3.9G     0  3.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda2                          974M  219M  688M  25% /boot
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/bb5dcb08fd6998aa3e438d3f2a43aeaea79fb22964abf42b4c5a869cde848b2a/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/55b43f1550428d3a82d2c2aebeb71bc9d53aac8185dd92644dfb27e806643b21/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d812b2347f599e207581e3cd6465013c5bf397aed3e4574a029f0289c42b3a4a/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/742e299d503c794052c173e34c78c75034e96870802856cfb15475478cbc6b01/merged
shm                                 64M   28K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/551b12883006bdf12d8a7602d862639b25cefdaac1623c62a0dfbc54970e6134/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/5f0ba3554d80c9b04823d09fed7a8c07c79f0059ba53d5a302ad981c6c419f42/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/aa50634d995d73db38c109365c7a7f330d3ba3dd8adf6901ab0668536787ea21/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/058f86b327e7efb701b5741a529157fdd01cc4785f3fb71a02355f3533664b5b/mounts/shm
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/d59ce13ad4c6790a0870b3f493b7093173c72da454eeaf03f96a311e16287d4b/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/474c51077a4becbc431b85ae8204648206cb3321ccf5b778882961d410ba32c2/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/fb516c559bd0d8368215a888320ab9624f6eac47fce9536ca6c3c4eddcb98af4/merged
overlay                             24G   22G  1.4G  95% /var/lib/docker/overlay2/f4d78c070438f018f39cd7a170594c84b6d5b1983eb9240f55e3c33c131503c9/merged
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/eea2e2895e013598106f35980d444b0b192a9ad60e8d12071edc729f1b38a9de/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/7df0cb94fb37ee61fdec8fb2db4fc4938fe56b8ac5809f109b9ed73fd6cb07d6/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M   16K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/5a1f23081c327b5e431b985f051c85c02eaf143db4bca9984cd55c5b69485e0e/mounts/shm
shm                                 64M  8.0K   64M   1% /var/lib/docker/containers/a8b8c20bdaa2ca9f934348ec9aa754399217f9e58e69e886deef5b0df3ab7074/mounts/shm
tmpfs                              789M     0  789M   0% /run/user/1000
```

Here is the output of `lvs`

```
LV        VG        Attr       LSize  Pool Origin Data%  Meta%  Move Log Cpy%Sync Convert
  ubuntu-lv ubuntu-vg -wi-ao---- 24.50g
```

Here is the output of `vgs`

```
VG        #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
  ubuntu-vg   1   1   0 wz--n- <49.00g <24.50g
```

Comment: Really sorry. Did it by mistake. My release is 18.04

Comment: Thanks for pointing out

Comment: `gparted` allows you to resize partitions, it's a GUI tool. BE CAREFUL as it won't ask you twice so don't go reformatting or deleting things becasue you won't get it back.

Comment: @darth_epoxy can I do it through command line?

Comment: You can use fdisk but I am unable to provide an answer as I don't know if LVM will be a problem. Try `fdisk -l` to see if the partition shows up then do some fdisk research. Resizing can create PMBR mismatches on GPT formatted partitions so I can only imagine LVM will be the same or worse. That's why they made gparted with the cleveer stuff built in.

Comment: Some more info: http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Answer (score 2):

In fact `ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` in not direct inside `sda3`.

Partition `sda3` is assigned to LVM PV (PhysicalVolume) size 49GiB
on this PV is created LVM VG (VolumeGroup): `ubuntu-vg` size 49GiB
in this VG is created LVM LV (LogicalVolume): `ubuntu-lv` size 24.5GiB

In VG is unassigned 24.50GiB, on disk sda is unassigned 90GiB space...

If you want increase size of `ubuntu-lv` but not increase size of VG/PV/sda3, 
you can enlarge `ubuntu-lv` at maximum of curent VG size 49GiB.

###### This add 5GiB from unassigned VG space to LV `ubuntu-lv`:

`sudo lvresize --size +5G --resizefs ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

###### This add all unassigned VG space to LV `ubuntu-lv`:

`sudo lvresize --extents +100%FREE --resizefs ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv`

( `--resizefs` is for resize filesystem on it to fit new LV size )