# need help interpreting fdisk and gnome-disk-utility output

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, backup, disk-usage, fdisk

I am on a fresh Ubuntu Server 22.04 install and during install, I think I might have chosen a filesystem which I do not understand:

```
cat /etc/*release

DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.1 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

My laptop comes with a 1 TB M2 SSD Disk. I can verify that using:

```
fdisk -l

...
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 953.87 GiB, 1024209543168 bytes, 2000409264 sectors
Disk model: Apacer AS2280P4 1TB                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 013CF2BF-BA0F-435D-814D-932E72606B27

Device           Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647    2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648    6397951    4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 6397952 2000406527 1994008576 950.8G Linux filesystem
...
```

The `gnome-disk-utility` also indicates the same:

[image: gnome-disk-utility]

I want to use this laptop for backing up some data with `rsync`, but when I look how much space I actually have with:

```
df -h

Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              1.6G  2.2M  1.6G   1% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv   98G   11G   83G  12% /
tmpfs                              7.8G   84K  7.8G   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.0G  134M  1.7G   8% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.1G  5.3M  1.1G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              1.6G  176K  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
```

I dont see the 1 TB mounted anywhere. There is only this weird `/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv` thing with only 98G.

Where is my 1 TB mountable space gone? I need it for backup purposes.

Comment: In the install, you created a logical volume, instead of a regular filesystem in a partition.  Generally, I'd recommend avoiding those unless you have a specific need, like raid, or encryption,....  Might be easier to reinstall and don't select the logical volume for your root.

Comment: Many with servers suggest LVM. But volumes are more advanced. Default install does not use the entire volume for / (root), so you can either add volumes for /home, other system volumes or expand / as desired. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume Info on LVM: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: fyi, i did a reinstall