# Re-allocating HDD/SSDs space

Tags: partitioning, mount, raid

This is my current "lsblk" output I want to re-allocate:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                      FSTYPE            TYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       linux_raid_member disk    3.6T
└─md127                   ext4              raid1   3.6T /mnt/raid1
sdb                       linux_raid_member disk    3.6T
└─md127                   ext4              raid1   3.6T /mnt/raid1
nvme0n1                                     disk  465.8G
├─nvme0n1p1               vfat              part      1G /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               ext4              part      2G /boot
└─nvme0n1p3               LVM2_member       part  462.7G
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4              lvm     100G /
```

These partitions were automatically installed via the Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS installation guide. I now want to change it and make it more "clear".
It should look like this when I use the "lsblk" command:

```
$ lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,TYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT
NAME                      FSTYPE            TYPE    SIZE MOUNTPOINT
sda                       linux_raid_member disk    3.6T
└─md1                     ext4              raid1   3.6T /mnt/raid1
sdb                       linux_raid_member disk    3.6T
└─md1                     ext4              raid1   3.6T /mnt/raid1
nvme0n1                                     disk  465.8G
├─nvme0n1p1               vfat              part      1G /boot/efi
├─nvme0n1p2               ext4              part      2G /boot
├─nvme0n1p3               ext4              part  462.7G /mnt/mySSDstorage
└─nvme0n1p4               ext4              part    100G /
```

Is this possible without formatting the drives? Thanks for any help!

Comment: Without formatting yes but working with partitions needs to have a complete back up first. Accidents and mistakes are common.

Comment: There are so many questions already on this I will not give you one just the search term that will display them and you can choose the one right for you. how to resize partitions

Comment: I do not use LVM, but have this in my notes for you to search for details. The solution is to use lvresize to resize the filesystem such that it takes up the entire partition. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume

Comment: @oldfred This was my solution. I researched lvm2 and this is indeed the better solution for my needs. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I wish to expand my LVM2 partition](https://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition)