# How to increase a partition and lvm

Tags: partitioning, lvm

This is my `lsblk` output:

```
lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop0          7:0    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1828
loop1          7:1    0 63.3M  1 loop /snap/core20/1852
loop2          7:2    0 67.2M  1 loop /snap/lxd/21835
loop3          7:3    0 91.9M  1 loop /snap/lxd/24061
loop4          7:4    0 49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18357
loop5          7:5    0 49.9M  1 loop /snap/snapd/18596
loop6          7:6    0  3.1G  0 loop /var/tmp
sda            8:0    0  155G  0 disk
├─sda1         8:1    0  1.1G  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2         8:2    0   74G  0 part
  └─vg0-root 253:0    0   74G  0 lvm  /
sr0           11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

I want to assign free size of sda to vg0-root.
Searching the internet has confused me and I am afraid that my data will be lost.

Comment: You may have to increase sda2, then expand LVM volume inside sda2. http://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/196125/how-can-i-resize-an-lvm-partition-i-e-physical-volume  & LVM as graphical organization, TheFu
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2485286

Comment: Or alternativelly add an sda3 and span lvm over both sda2 and sda3.