# Fresh install of 22.04 server, 512GB SDD, but file system only shows 88GB free?

Tags: server, mount, 22.04, hard-drive, samba

I have a fresh install of 22.04 Server. The machine has a 512G SDD. I selected to use the whole disk when installing it. I installed the typical LAMP server stuff, put WP on there to mess around, and I installed Samba and got it working from my other Ubuntu desktop (20.04). I haven't tried it from her laptop yet, but I'll cross that bridge when I get there. I'm moving some stuff off of my PC to the server, and I noticed that it says the shared directory is only 105G.

The main purpose of this machine is to store YEARS of photos and videos (about 301GB worth) from my wife's laptop (and my machine to free up some space). It's old and it's dying a slow death. We don't want to lose the photos and videos of the kiddos and stuff.

I don't know if I did something wrong, or what. The path for the samba share is `/svr/samba/Public_Share`.

I come to you gurus, hat in hand. I need some guidance on this one.

Here is `df -H` output:

```
$df -H
Filesystem                         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
tmpfs                              800M   13M  787M   2% /run
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv  106G   15G   86G  15% /
tmpfs                              4.0G     0  4.0G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs                              5.3M     0  5.3M   0% /run/lock
/dev/nvme0n1p2                     2.1G  137M  1.8G   8% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p1                     1.2G  6.4M  1.2G   1% /boot/efi
tmpfs                              800M  4.1k  800M   1% /run/user/1000
```

And here is `fdisk -l` output:

```
Disk /dev/loop0: 63.45 MiB, 66531328 bytes, 129944 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop1: 111.95 MiB, 117387264 bytes, 229272 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop2: 53.26 MiB, 55844864 bytes, 109072 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop3: 40.84 MiB, 42827776 bytes, 83648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/loop4: 63.46 MiB, 66547712 bytes, 129976 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 476.94 GiB, 512110190592 bytes, 1000215216 sectors
Disk model: KBG50ZNV512G KIOXIA                     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5265B0EC-CF6B-41D8-BA96-FEB2E781AAC0

Device           Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1    2048    2203647   2201600     1G EFI System
/dev/nvme0n1p2 2203648    6397951   4194304     2G Linux filesystem
/dev/nvme0n1p3 6397952 1000212479 993814528 473.9G Linux filesystem  <<< (LOOK AT THIS!)

Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 100 GiB, 107374182400 bytes, 209715200 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

It shows I have ***474G of space*** so where is it? Or, where should I put that samba share? I'm so confused right now...

Comment: Well...I just learned about LVM, and that's why I can't see the other 373G. But, does LVM extend the volume automatically, or does it have to be done manually?

Comment: It does not immediately allocate all the space. Installer does not know how you want to use it. More volumes, larger volumes? And volumes can easily be resized while running unlike partitions. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2444855&p=13963156#post13963156 https://askubuntu.com/questions/852019/i-wish-to-expand-my-lvm2-partition Do not post unformatted data. And loops are not partitions, but just your snap apps. Why do you have snaps in a server?

Comment: I'm a reconstituted noob. I used to tinker with FreeBSD and Debian, but that was 20 years ago. This is a fresh default install of 22.04, that's why there are snaps.